# 'unresolved external symbol _SDL_main referenced in function' error in Visual Studio 2012 with SDL2

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, sdl

Ive been trawling the internet for weeks and none of the answers worked.
My code is:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{
    SDL_Window *win = nullptr;
    SDL_Renderer *ren = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface *bmp = nullptr;
    SDL_Texture *tex = nullptr;


    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING))
    {
        cout << SDL_GetError();
        return 1;
    }

    win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    if (win == nullptr)
    {
        cout << SDL_GetError();
        return 1;
    }

    ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

    if (ren == nullptr)
    {
        cout << SDL_GetError();
        return 1;
    }

    bmp = SDL_LoadBMP("hello.bmp");
    tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, bmp);
    SDL_FreeSurface(bmp);

    SDL_RenderClear(ren);
    SDL_RenderCopy(ren, tex, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(ren);

    SDL_Delay(2000);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;

}
```

Ive tried `#undef main` (Which comes up with another error) & and even redefining it to no avail. Ive also tried several other attempts such as creating it as a Windows Console project.

Anyway I really hope you can help me and others.
Cheers,

user (insert psuedo-randomly generated integer here)

Comment: **Answer**: Thanks to Nemanja Boric I have come to a conclusion, if you are having similar problems follow his answer below. (To be specific exchange `int main(int argc, char** argv[])` with `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature of your `main` function is incorrect.

This line:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv[])
```

should be

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Comment: No why? Are you referring to how I havent posted an answer? Ill do that now.

Comment: @user2752347 No, you just need to accept the answer :) - there is a tick mark left to my answer!